# mysql between statement using the current year

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm drawing a blank and need some help figuring out the right syntax for a between statement in mysql

I'm doing a report and need to display the Year to Date information.  I would like to have the query figure out the year and put it in the BETWEEN statement.

if I do the following it works:

```
AND aa.entry_date BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-04-30"
```

But I want the query to figure out what the year is and use that instead...kind of like this:

```
AND aa.entry_date BETWEEN Year(CURDATE())+ "-01-01" AND "2014-04-30"
```

Except this doesn't work...what is the right syntax to accomplish this in mysql?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not positive, but have you tried the CONCAT function? `CONCAT( YEAR(CURDATE()), "-01-01" )`. No idea if the function works outside of columns concatenation.

Comment: worked perfectly!  Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use proper MySQL syntax.  `+` the is SQL Server way to concat strings.  `concat()` is MySQL, '+' is just numeric addition:

```
 AND aa.entry_date BETWEEN date(concat(Year(CURDATE()), '-01-01')) AND date('2014-04-30')
```

Notice that I also switched to using single quotes for the string and date constants.  This usually prevents other confusion in the code.

Comment: awesome gordon, thansk!

Comment: +1. The `DATE_FORMAT( ,'%Y-01-01')` function is a convenient alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the DATE_FORMAT function, and supply a literal for the month and day.

For example:

```
aa.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01') AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of futzing around with CONCAT() and implicit conversion, you could use MAKEDATE() and YEAR() with CURDATE():

```
AND aa.entry_date BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND CURDATE()
```

(Untested, based on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
AND YEAR(aa.entry_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

will select everything from this year without using the BETWEEN statement.

Comment: N.B. wrapping the column in a function will disable MySQL's ability to use an index range scan operation (to satisfy the predicate).

Comment: @spencer7593, you're right. I can't downvote my own post. Can you do it for me?

Comment: I wouldn't downvote your answer; it's a good answer; it's valid and will return all `entry_date` values in the current year. For all we know, there may not be an index with `entry_date` as a leading column, the query may already be using a more appropriate index (we can't tell from the information provided in the OP question). Sometimes, wrapping the column in a function *is* the most appropriate approach. But I think many are caught unaware that doing this disables a range scan operation.